# phpunit assertNull gets zend_mm_heap corrupted

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

When using scalar:

```
$null = null;
$this->assertNull($null);
```

Test OK

```
$null = 'not null';
$this->assertNull($null);
```

Test Fail

When using Object:

```
$this->assertEquals(null, $menu->getChild('Projects'));
```

Test OK or Fail regarding if $menu->getChild('Projects') is null or not

```
$this->assertNull($menu->getChild('Projects'));
```

Hangs and I get the error: **zend_mm_heap corrupted**

When using *AssertNull*, I do not get the same behavior as *AssertEquals(null, $var)*;
For the moment, I ban the use of AssertNull, but I was wondering if one of you could explain what's going on...

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem and also found my php was hanging on the print_r line. Changed to `assertEquals` solves my problem, thanks. I've done some more debugging but still have no clue how to fix it properly

Answer (score 2):

The object is of type : *Knp\Menu\MenuItem* (An object from the knpmenu php library)

The problem is a recursivity problem linked with a function from the phpunit library.

class: *PHPUnit/Util/Type*

function: *recursiveExport*

```
preg_match_all('/\n            \[(\w+)\] => Array\s+\*RECURSION\*/', print_r($value, TRUE), $matches);
```

[image: $value content]

As you see, the child has a reference to the parent object, that is the reason for the deadlock.

**But** when I read the documentation of *print_r*, it is stated:

> Prior to PHP 4.0.4, print_r() will continue forever if given an array or object that contains a direct or indirect reference to itself. An example is print_r($GLOBALS) because $GLOBALS is itself a global variable that contains a reference to itself.

I'm using :

> PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 23:48:31)

My conclusion for the moment, is **NOT** to use *assertNull* but *AssertEquals*

Comment: I would be glad if someone could take take the point and explain me if the problem is coming from PHP or from me?