# PHPUnit increasing memory kills process itself

Tags: symfony, memory, mocking, phpunit

I have the problem that my unit tests for some assertions and mocks are running out of memory. The memory is increasing each second 100MB and then killing the phpunit process when it's reaching the maximum available memory.

I would expect that the test is failing with some helpful message but because it's just killing the process I don't really know how to debug it.

Any idea why or how to debug the behaviour?

Comment: if this happens you have a problem with the software to be tested or the unit tests you wrote. usually PHPUnit will not behave in such a way. would need to see your unit test to say more

Comment: After some research I found this stackoverflow question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764826/phpunit-assertnull-gets-zend-mm-heap-corrupted

It's almost the same behaviour for me. If I assertNull and an object is given it's just running out of memory. assertEquals with null is failing like expected. Could be a similar problem for the mocks?!
Anyway it would be interesting to understand why it's failing with assertEquals and running out of memory with assertNull

Answer (score 5):

I have had problems with running out of memory before. On thing I found helpful was to turn off the garbage collection with the tests.

```
$ phpunit -d zend.enable_gc=0
```

As for debugging, try

```
$ phpunit --debug
```

to figure out which test is causing the problem. From here, you need to debug, the same way you would any bug.